# ZF proving the existence of a singleton?

Tags: set-theory

I have to show that if $A$ is a set, then $\{A\}$ is a set. I get that $\{A, A\}$ is a set by pairing, but the only argument I've seen that $\{A\}$ is a set is because $\{A, A\} = \{A\}$ by extension. However, extensionality says that
\begin{equation*}
\forall x \forall y (\forall z (z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y) \leftrightarrow x = y)
\end{equation*}
but $x$, $y$ and $z$ range over $sets$. That is, if $x$ and $y$ are already sets, then $x = y$ iff $x$ and $y$ have the same members. So it seems like saying that $\{A, A\}$ is a set, and $\{A\} = \{A, A\}$ by extension assumes already that $\{A\}$ is a set in order to apply the axiom. However, this is what I want to prove. I understand that I might get away with the class $\{A\} = \{x : x = A\}$ is a set by applying extensionality to it and the set $\{A, A\}$, but the book I am using hasn't given a treatment of classes at this point.

Comment: Don't underestimate the value of revisiting definitions! Remember that all the "real" sentences of ZF include only the symbols of first order logic and "$\in$". Anything else is a handy abbreviation, and this sort of confusion is often cleared up by thinking about what $\{-\}$ is an abbreviation for.

Comment: As [Malice](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/102781/) suggests, you are getting confused by the notation. We use $\{A\}$ only *after* we have proved that there is a unique set $z$ with the property that $\forall y\,(y\in z\leftrightarrow y=A)$. Once we know this, then $\{A\}$ is our shorthand for this set $z$. So, the task is: Prove that indeed there is a unique set $z$ with that property. In fact, prove that "$\{A,A\}$" is that set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\{A, A\}$ and $\{A\}$ are the same set by definition.

Pairing applied to $A$ says that there exists a set $S$ such that $x \in S \iff x = A \vee x = A$, which is equivalent to $x \in S \iff x = A$.

Comment: It's not by definition; as you say it follows from the logical equivalence of $P\lor P$ and $P$.

Comment: Well yes that is what I actually meant to say!